# Android intent-filter for uncommon mime-type

Tags: android, android-manifest, mime-types, intentfilter

I'm trying to write an application that deals with sgf files (game records for Go game).

I want to be able to open sgf files from file explorer, mailbox or internet.

I tried this in the manifest :

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <data android:mimeType="application/x-go-sgf" />
</intent-filter>
```

Unfortunately it won't works, despite it was working with "text/csv".
However, the following code display "application/x-go-sgf" :

```
MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
String mt = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension("sgf");
Log.d("mime", mt); // application/x-go-sgf
```

Android seems to be aware of sgf files, so why am I not able to open these files with my application from the file explorer?

Comment: What is not working? How / where is the `VIEW` intent generated?

Comment: is there an application that can open these files? For these types of issues it's usually helpful to use aLogCat on your phone to view how other applications are sending/receiving intent's for the file type in question. For example, if you go to a file explorer app and long-press -> View on an SGF file, it will send the file to another application via Intent. If you look aLogCat, it will show you how that file was sent, including the mimetype and action.

Comment: @zapl:
It is not working because i can't open a sgf file from a file explorer or mailbox, the view is not associated. But similar code with "text/csv" mimetype allow me to open csv file from file explorer and mailbox.

Comment: @Gophermofur: I found some application that can open sgf files, but only with built-in file explorer. I found no one which can open these files from file explorer or Mailbox.

Comment: What did your `Lod.d("mime", mt)` statement print out for the mimetype? Also, show us the code where you are creating/sending the intent.

Comment: I edited my first message.

Log.d("mime", mt) print "application/x-go-sgf", as I said above.

There is no code where I am sending intent.

I am writing an application which read sgf files. I can open these file with a built-in explorer, but I want also be able to open these file directly from the internet, or from a file explorer. The problem is I can't do that with this intent-filter, despite it is working for csv file when I replace application/x-go-sgf by text/csv.